# Karma coverage always shows 100%

Tags: angularjs, code-coverage, karma-runner

My karma.conf.js files looks like this :

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Tue Jun 11 2013 14:14:12 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)


// base path, that will be used to resolve files and exclude
basePath = '';


// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files = [
    JASMINE,
    JASMINE_ADAPTER,
    '../Scripts/angular/angular.js',
    '../Scripts/angular/restangular/underscore-min.js',
    '../Scripts/angular/restangular/restangular-min.js',
    '../Scripts/angular/angular-*.js',
    '../Scripts/angular/angular-test/angular-*.js',
    '../Scripts/angular/angular-ui/*.js',
    '../Scripts/angular/angular-strap/*.js',
    '../Scripts/angular/angular-http-auth/*.js',
    '../uifw/scripts/ui-framework-angular.js',
    '../app/app.js',
    '../app/**/*.js',
    'unit/**/*.js'
];


// list of files to exclude
exclude = [
  '../Scripts/angular/angular-test/angular-scenario.js'
];

preprocessors = {
  '**/../app/**/*.js': 'coverage'
};



coverageReporter = {
    type: 'html',
    dir: 'coverage/'
};


// test results reporter to use
// possible values: 'dots', 'progress', 'junit'
reporters = ['progress', 'coverage'];


// web server port
port = 9876;


// cli runner port
runnerPort = 9100;


// enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
colors = true;


// level of logging
// possible values: LOG_DISABLE || LOG_ERROR || LOG_WARN || LOG_INFO || LOG_DEBUG
logLevel = LOG_DEBUG;


// enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
autoWatch = true;


// Start these browsers, currently available:
// - Chrome
// - ChromeCanary
// - Firefox
// - Opera
// - Safari (only Mac)
// - PhantomJS
// - IE (only Windows)
browsers = ['Chrome'];


// If browser does not capture in given timeout [ms], kill it
captureTimeout = 60000;


// Continuous Integration mode
// if true, it capture browsers, run tests and exit
singleRun = false;
```

My folder structure looks like this :

```
Root
 |__ App
 |__ Scripts
 |__ Tests
 |__ .... other folders
```

`Karma.conf.js` is located inside the tests folder. `Karma start karma.conf.j` is run from within the `tests` folder.

My tests run and a coverage folder is created, but coverage always shows 100%.

[image: Coverage]

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

In fact it turned out to be a simple answer. the `preprocessors = {
      '**/../app/**/*.js': 'coverage'
    };`
 no longer needs to be prefixed with `**`

See [this for more details](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/karma-users/rLAVKN0-WJw)

Answer (score 2):

Set up webpack with istanbul-instrumenter-loader got me on the right track.

`{
   test: /\.ts/,
   include: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
   loader: 'istanbul-instrumenter-loader',
   enforce: 'post'
}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `ANGULAR_SCENARIO_ADAPTER`. `Karma` doesn't use `JASMINE_ADAPTER`.

Comment: I think your confusing unit testing with end-2-end testing. My question is about unit testing. See my edit for the answer that worked for me.

Comment: I have the same problem and I think it is not a matter of adapter. Jasmine tests are actually being executed and Karma does use the jasmine adapter. The problem is the coverage report is always 100%.

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems like your problem is that you are unable to find any of the files you are trying to generate coverage for. Your report does say that 0/0 lines are ran, 0/0 statements and so on.

I had a similar problem that was caused by me using lower case letters instead of upper case ones and it seems you might have the same problem as you have a folder named "App" but you reference it with "app" in the config. See if you can get it to work by writing `**/../App/**/*.js': 'coverage'`

Also I am not sure but I think you should write `../App/**/*.js': 'coverage'` instead of `**/../App/**/*.js': 'coverage'`